# Getting column count of the MySQL output with Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connectivity

I want to know how to get the column count of resulting output in MySQL.

I searched this site for the same question but i'm little different.

I want to get the column count of resulting output not of the table.

I want to know how many columns are there in the resulting output when a query is passed.

Thanxx in advance!

Comment: Where count should be calculated: on mysq or java side? How do you fetch result in java?

Comment: count could be calculated on any side if its in mysql then i could get it in Java. But i want to use the count in Java. So it doesn't mind me where the calculation takes place. I just want the number of columns in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ResultSetMetaData#getColumnCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) method to get the count in java

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

Comment: I'm new to Java and i haven't used it before. Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

you don´t need a `ResultSetMetaData` variable, just try this code:

```
int columCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
```

the `rs` is a `Resulset`.